# Are OpenPGP-encrypted files encrypted symmetrically or with a private key?

Tags: encryption, pgp, decryption, asymmetric, openpgp

When you decrypt a personal file from another sender, do you decrypt that file with your own private key or is it a symmetric key?

I've been searching for it on the net for a while, but it's very confusing: one website says 'with the private key', another one says 'with a symmetric key'.

Comment: With a symmetric key.  This symmetric key is part (at the beginning) of the cyphertext, and is encrypted with the public key (so it can be decrypted with the private one).

Comment: Dupe http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/why-does-pgp-use-symmetric-encryption-and-rsa/ and cross http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/why-the-symmetric-key-layer-in-pgp

Answer (score 5):

Generally, OpenPGP uses a hybrid approach: the message itself is encrypted with a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES and a distinct *session key* (a large random number individually created for each encrypted message), and then the session key is encrypted using public/private key cryptography. This combines the advantages of both concepts: symmetric encryption is very fast, while public/private key cryptography enables advanced key management functionality (ie., having split public and private keys).

So while technically the file is encrypted with symmetric cryptography, this is not directly visible to the user. It is not totally wrong if you say the file is encrypted through public/private key encryption, as the session key is not accessible without the private key.

OpenPGP also allows plain symmetric encryption, where the session key is derived from a passphrase without any public/private key cryptography.

Comment: Note that at least GnuPG allows outputting the symmetric key for a given message directly by using `--show-session-key`. And of course, there is `--symmetric`/`-c`.

Answer (score 2):

For Open PGP and email Encryption in general, a hybrid approach is used. The reason for using a hybrid approach is that asymmetric encryption is computationally expensive and has some proven weakness with large amount of content. So the approach is as follows.

1. Encrypt the data with a Symmetric encryption algorithm, say AES.
2. Encrypt the symmetric encryption key with the public key of the recipient.
3. Append the encrypted key to the encrypted message and send the email to the recipient.

Only the recipient can decrypt and obtain the AES key as the same was encrypted using public key of the recipient. The recipient can then use the AES key to decrypt the cyphertext.